# Chairs are listed from 1 to 11. We sits randomly 4 girls and 7 boy. Which the probability of a boy sit in the chair 5?

Tags: probability

Chairs are listed from 1 to 11. We sits randomly 4 girls and 7 boy. Which the probability of a boy sit in the chair 5?

My work:

Let $S$ the sample space, then $|S|=11!$

Let $E:$"a boy sit in the chair 5." a event.

Consider $E^c$ in other words, a girl sit in the chair 5.

Then, we can order the other boys/girls of the next form: $10!$

For example, one solution is:  G G G B B G B B B B B B is one form of sit the boys and the girl. Then if we set a girl in the chair 5 then we have $10!$ of sit the other persons.

This implies

$|E^c|=10!$

Then

$P(E)=-\frac{10!}{11!}+1$

Is good the reasoning?

Comment: You are working a bit to hard.  But you missed that there are 4 possible girls that could be seated in chair 5.  $P(E) = 1 - \frac {4\cdot 10!}{11!} = \frac {7}{11}$.

Comment: Thanks @DougM i missed that! you think the reasoning is good?

Comment: The logic is sound, but a little bit overwrought.  There are 7 boys and 11 chairs and each boy is as likely to sit in chair 5 as any other chair.

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking. You have $4$ girls and $7$ boys. Sit them down one at a time. What is the probability that the first person is a boy? By symmetry, it's the same as the fifth chair.

Answer (score 2):

If we don't sit the boys and girls down in a chair, but just randomly pick one, what is the chance that it is a boy?

Now think: is having a random person sit on chair $5$ any different?